# Android media player problem on multiple clicks

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

While developing Android app I faced an issue.. I used mediaplayer on button click but when running the app on **lower end smartphones**, when I click the button multiple times the media is not played (on clicking 20-25 times) this does not happen in mid end and **high end phones**. If anyone faced this problem and have a solution kindly share the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow :). Question: do you spawn a new instance of `MediaPlayer` each times you consume the click event on your button ? If so, you shouldn't. The most obvious reasons: performance. Second, there is a limitiation on codec initialization per device and usually on lower-end, its a few.. Please provide code sample to better understand your issue.

Comment: Disable that button as soon as you started the player.

Comment: @blackapps But that's the functionality I need that button working every time

Comment: @machovich I created the instance of the Mediaplayer in onCreate() method. In the button click event I just have a mediaplayer.start()

Comment: Why do you have to start the player more than once?

Comment: @blackapps the scenario is like I have to play a shouting sound on button click every time so for that, in the button click event I used mediaplayer.start() to start the sound

Comment: I believe Android offer a different API when you need to play short sound (like notifications bells). If that's you need / want, have a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Actually while working with media player we must use mediaplayer.reset() instead of mediaplayer.stop() to.stop the player, which resets the media.
When using stop there occurs a pause in the media which causes the app to crash. But this is handled by the Oreo and higher versions whereas Android N and lesser versions cannot handle this. so this caused the sound to crash.

Thankyou all for the responses